# Configuration of WebMethods Client to connect to WebSphere JMS (not WebSphere MQ)

Tags: jms, weblogic, integration, message-queue, websphere-7

Currently I have setup two queues on WebSphere 7. One for sending and one for recieving messages.

I have configured a activation spec on the receiving queue and the messages are consumed fine by a Message Bean.

Also I have written a client that can run on a separate jvm which can send messages fine to the queue.

I am sure that the queues work.

Now I want to know how can I connect them with WebMetods. I know that WebMethods supports JBoss and WebLogic but no support for WebSphere.

I should be able to get this working just by providing:
a provider url -  "iiop://172.17.13.65:2809"
a connection factory - "jms/ConnectionFactroy"
a queue name- "jms/inQueue"
and an initial context - "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"

(at least this is what my client is using)

Is there anybody that has resolved this issue? And what are the steps they took?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to get this implementation happen.

To solve this Web Methods had to import some jar files for Client JMS:
com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0 + com.ibm.ws.orb_7.0.0 + com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_7.0.0

And use a bootstrap of this type PROVIDER_URL: "iiop://natasha:2810"

Alaso these details as previously mentioned:

a factory - "jms/ConnectionFactroy" 
a queue name- "jms/inQueue" and 
an initial context - "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"